# JSHINT: how to disable the warning Missing space after anonymous 'function'

Tags: javascript, jshint

I got warning in jshint

```
  '[L76:C24] Missing space after 'function''
```

I follows **Nicholas Zakkas** *Maintainable javascript* styles where there is no space after anonymous function. How to remove this warning in jshint?

**.jshintrc**

```
{
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es5": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": true,
    "camelcase": true,
    "curly": true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "latedef": true,
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "quotmark": "single",
    "regexp": true,
    "undef": true,
    "unused": true,
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "smarttabs": true
}
```

Comment: to turn off mixed spaces and tabs warning you can set `"smarttabs": true` in the `.jshintrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`indent` option used to force the `white` option on](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/667). This is no longer the case in the most recent version.

Try adding the following to your .jshintrc:

```
"white": false
```

Answer (score 8):

Normally you have error notices in the following form in your CLI:

> [L426:C63] W030: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Now you can take that `WXXX` ID and add it to your `options` subobject. Simply add

```
"-WXXX" : true
```

for whatever notice you want to turn off. Keep in mind that you only can turn off all notices of a type and no specific notices on specific lines or lines in only single files. Still, you can add different tasks for different files and ignore different hints/notices that way.

Here's an example for `grunt-contrib-jshint`. Note: `site.scripts` comes from a YAML file that holds the config.

```
jshint : {
    dev : {
        options : {
            // Ignore: "Bad" line break
            "-W014" : true
        },
        src: [ "<%= site.scripts %>/**/*.js" ]
    }
}
```